# Should you not go above max VGS for a Nmos?

Tags: transistors, nmos

I wanted to switch a relay with a raspberry zero, which uses 3.3v,
after looking at my 16 years old electronic engineering notes (I'm in IT now), I moderatly re-understood how nmos works (controlled by tension only, once activated is equivalent to a resistor, RDsOn).

They are tension operated not current operated so less math to do, that is why I choose them.
After some quick googling I found that some people use IRLZ34N.

So I did this :

[image]

In order to switch on a waterpump for 15 seconds each day.
It has been working for 2 months now.

My question is, why doesn't it blow up? since I exceeded Max VGS.

Thanks.

Comment: Vgs(th) is a "Turn ON" voltage. And voltage larger than this will "open" the MOSFET (Id = 0.25mA). And the maximum voltage that you can apply directly across the gate-source terminal is +/-16V. See the datasheet Absolute Maximum Ratings Vgs. Also, take a look ar fig .1   http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlz34n.pdf Which shows that if you want to operate the NMOS as a switch the Vgs voltage must be larger than Vgs(th).

Comment: @G36 oh max and min VGS(th) means that some transistor might have 1V and some 2V?

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is a spread between the VGS(th) the NMOS will have in real-life. So, if you have a bucket of  IRLZ34N the VGS(th) will lay between 1V..2V. But all will be "open"  if Vgs > 2V ( but this does not mean full-on).

Comment: allright, I thought it meant that VGS(th) could only be between 1v and 2vn Thanks

Comment: Vgs(th) will be between 1 and 2 V. The Vgs that you apply to turn the transistor "on" must be above Vgs(th). The specs for Rds(on) will tell  you how much above it should be to get a good low-resistance channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max VGS is given in the Absolute Maximum Ratings section of the datasheet it is given as 16V in the one I have seen for this device. [irflz34n datasheet](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irlz34n.pdf)

The number you are looking at is the threshold voltage which is where the transistor is fully on under low current conditions. It is given a minimum and maximum value for any one transistor because of variations in manufacturing changing this value. This is not intended to give the operating range for the transistor.

Using the transistor as a switch it is good to drive the gate higher than the threshold voltage. Somewhere in the data sheet you should have a graph of either RDSon or drain current at various gate voltages. From this you can see that the ability to drive higher currents is better as you drive the gate voltage higher.